# Can't insert specific timestamp to table

Tags: datetime, mysql5

I can not insert timestamp value `'2015-01-07 00:00:00'` into my database.

This issue works for any hour between `2015-01-07 00:00:00` and `2015-01-07 01:00:00`

This works ONLY for the 7th of January of 2015.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

protocol_version    10
version 5.1.50-community
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine ia32
version_compile_os  Win32
```

==

```
CREATE TABLE `eventtest3` (
  `event_dt` TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

0 row(s) affected
```

==

And my insert query is:

```
1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: INSERT INTO eventtest3 (event_dt) VALUES('2015-01-07 00:00:00')

Error Code: 1292
Incorrect datetime value: '2015-01-07 00:00:00' for column 'event_dt' at row 1
```

==

Working queries:

```
Query: INSERT INTO eventtest3 (event_dt) VALUES('2017-01-07 00:00:00')
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
1 row(s) affected

Query: INSERT INTO eventtest3 (event_dt) VALUES('2014-01-07 00:00:00')
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
1 row(s) affected

Query: INSERT INTO eventtest3 (event_dt) VALUES('2016-01-07 00:00:00')
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
1 row(s) affected

1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings
Query: INSERT INTO eventtest3 (event_dt) VALUES('2015-01-31 05:07:09')
1 row(s) affected
```

There is no time shifting here or there on this date so I dont think this issue is because of timezone settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to check if mysql.time_zone* tables are empty, download timezones information from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html and just replace tables with stopped mysql service.

I don't really know HOW this can help with 7th of January of 2015 but it really does.